# Add Specific Attachments to Docusign envelope

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, docusign

I have Docusign for Salesforce set up with a Lightning Component custom button the generates the URL reqd to select the correct template, fill in various merge fields and redirect to Docusign. What i was wondering is whether anyone knows if its possible to query a specific attachment from a *related* record to the one the doc is being send from and attach this file to the email that gets sent by Docusign.

It doesn't need any merge fields or signing and is just for info only.